# java commandline: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when JAR is in current folder but not when it is decompressed

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classnotfoundexception

A simple Java code has this line:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

The code compiles to generate .class file. But when I try to run this .class file using Java command line, it fail at runtime at above line with exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

In current folder I already have put required sqljdbc41.jar which has SQLServerDriver driver. I also have included current folder "." in CLASSPATH environment variable (I am on Windows btw).

However, above code line does not give any problem and code runs successfully when I unzip sqljdbc41.jar, which creates folder hierarchy "com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc" in the current folder.

Java information:

> java version "1.8.0_202"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)

Where I am missing? How and where exactly shall I specify CLASSPATH? How can I include dependent jar files when running code using java command line?

Comment: How are you actually running the Jar file? How are you specifying the classpath when you run the Jar file? What version of Java?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for asking clarifications. I run .class file. And sqljdbc41.jar is dependency. I added more info to the question. CLASSPATH is set as environment variable as I read it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the 4-year-old JDBC driver [sqljdbc41.jar](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54670) directly, you should use a dependency management tool, for example, [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html). Then, as described in the [driver home page](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc), it can be added to a Maven project by adding it as a dependency in the POM file with the following code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.1.jre17</version>
</dependency>
```

See the [Maven Central Repository](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc) for the latest version.